# Lg volt freezing on home screen

Tags: system-freeze, lg-volt

Recently my LG Volt has started to freeze on my home page when I turn my phone back on.  Will not open when I swipe or tap.  I have to do a power off-restart in order to get it to work, and sometimes I have to do this several times before the swipe function will respond. I've tried removing the battery but even this only helps for a short time.  Any suggestions on a fix or has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Is this freezing on the lock screen or the launcher? It is a bit unclear.

Comment: I think it is the launcher.  I will be using the phone and close my home screen. Several minutes later, or longer I click my home button to wake up my phone, the launch page opens, but will not respond to tapping or swiping.

Answer (score 1):

Since you confirmed it's the launcher, this isn't too bad of a fix.

Open settings, go to apps, then swipe to all. Scroll until you find an app called Laucher. This is actually your home screen. 
***WARNING! This will erase your home screen. Take screenshots if you want to put it back to the way it was!***
Clear the cache and data of the app.
Restart your phone. If this fixes it, congrats! Otherwise, you can try downloading a new launcher from the Google Play Store or factory reset the device.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion? **Flash a custom ROM.**

I have an enemity with stock ROMs I've not managed to attribute to a definite cause myself; but I can surely tell you this much: I'm using **Lineage OS** and I love it.

I wouldn't know if the hardware limitations of your device will create a problem with third party ROMs. But  **Lineage OS is the lightest of operating systems as shown by benchmarks**. It has a great community, vast technical support and dependibility.

So go for a custom ROM and flash it at the earliest if you can. Quit having to put up with buggy firmware.